# can only ssh unidirectional

Tags: ssh, tcpdump

I have two centos 7.2 server. One machine ip is 
10.104.196.18, another machine is 10.240.197.21. I can successfully ssh from 10.104.196.18 to 10.240.197.21. But failed to ssh into 10.104.196.18 from 10.240.197.21.

The ssh log is like this:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.104.196.18 [10.104.196.18] port 6990.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
```

The sshd log is like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# /usr/sbin/sshd -dD -p 10000
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 3 ECDSA
debug1: private host key: #2 type 4 ED25519
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-dD'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='10000'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 10000 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 10000.
debug1: Bind to port 10000 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 10000.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 10.96.203.72 port 49845 on 10.240.197.21 port 10000
```

So it's apparently both the client and server pending at exchange identities.
And from tcpdump we are confirmed by packets analysis.

tcpdump from 10.240.197.21

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -i enp22s0f3 host 10.104.196.18 -s0 -vv -X -c 1000
tcpdump: listening on enp22s0f3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
13:22:37.402757 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25620, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0x9eae (incorrect -> 0x290b), seq 2201485227, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 300522431 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 003c 6414 4000 4006 3828 0af0 c515  E..<d.@.@.8(....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffab 0000 0000  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  a002 7210 9eae 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..r.............
        0x0030:  11e9 9bbf 0000 0000 0103 0307            ............
13:22:37.403162 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.104.196.18.ssh > localhost.localdomain.56770: Flags [S.], cksum 0x2b22 (correct), seq 4104511511, ack 2201485228, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 312416107 ecr 300522431,nop,wscale 7], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 3c06 a03c 0a68 c412  E..<..@.<..<.h..
        0x0010:  0af0 c515 0016 ddc2 f4a5 e017 8337 ffac  .............7..
        0x0020:  a012 7120 2b22 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..q.+"..........
        0x0030:  129f 176b 11e9 9bbf 0103 0307            ...k........
13:22:37.403219 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25621, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0x9ea6 (incorrect -> 0xca29), seq 1, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300522431 ecr 312416107], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0034 6415 4000 4006 382f 0af0 c515  E..4d.@.@.8/....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8010 00e5 9ea6 0000 0101 080a 11e9 9bbf  ................
        0x0030:  129f 176b                                ...k
13:22:37.403801 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25622, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0xd432), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300522432 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 6416 4000 4006 3817 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11e9 9bc0  ................
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
13:22:37.604502 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25623, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0xd369), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300522633 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 6417 4000 4006 3816 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11e9 9c89  ................
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
13:22:37.808499 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25624, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0xd29d), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300522837 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 6418 4000 4006 3815 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11e9 9d55  ...............U
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
13:22:38.217526 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25625, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0xd104), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300523246 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 6419 4000 4006 3814 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11e9 9eee  ................
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
13:22:39.035515 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25626, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0xcdd2), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300524064 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 641a 4000 4006 3813 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11e9 a220  ................
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
13:22:40.671529 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25627, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0xc76e), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300525700 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 641b 4000 4006 3812 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11e9 a884  ................
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
13:22:43.947534 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25628, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0xbaa2), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300528976 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 641c 4000 4006 3811 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11e9 b550  ...............P
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
13:22:50.491548 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25629, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0xa112), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300535520 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 641d 4000 4006 3810 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11e9 cee0  ................
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
13:23:03.579533 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25630, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0x6df2), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300548608 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 641e 4000 4006 380f 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11ea 0200  ................
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
13:23:29.755543 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25631, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0x07b2), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300574784 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 641f 4000 4006 380e 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11ea 6840  ..............h@
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
13:24:22.171532 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25632, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    localhost.localdomain.56770 > 10.104.196.18.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9ebd (incorrect -> 0x3af1), seq 1:24, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300627200 ecr 312416107], length 23
        0x0000:  4500 004b 6420 4000 4006 380d 0af0 c515  E..Kd.@.@.8.....
        0x0010:  0a68 c412 ddc2 0016 8337 ffac f4a5 e018  .h.......7......
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 9ebd 0000 0101 080a 11eb 3500  ..............5.
        0x0030:  129f 176b 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ...kSSH-2.0-Open
        0x0040:  5353 485f 362e 362e 310d 0a              SSH_6.6.1..
```

tcpdump from 10.104.196.18

```
01:22:37.400147 IP 10.240.197.21.56770 > localhost.localdomain.ssh: Flags [S], seq 2201485227, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 300522431 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
01:22:37.400219 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [S.], seq 4104511511, ack 2201485228, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 312416107 ecr 300522431,nop,wscale 7], length 0
01:22:37.400476 IP 10.240.197.21.56770 > localhost.localdomain.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 300522431 ecr 312416107], length 0
01:22:37.426399 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 312416133 ecr 300522431], length 23
01:22:37.626271 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 312416333 ecr 300522431], length 23
01:22:37.831584 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 312416538 ecr 300522431], length 23
01:22:38.242549 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 312416949 ecr 300522431], length 23
01:22:39.065132 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 312417772 ecr 300522431], length 23
01:22:40.709282 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 312419416 ecr 300522431], length 23
01:22:43.997804 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 312422704 ecr 300522431], length 23
01:22:50.574310 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 312429281 ecr 300522431], length 23
01:23:03.725361 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 312442432 ecr 300522431], length 23
01:23:30.029758 IP localhost.localdomain.ssh > 10.240.197.21.56770: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 312468736 ecr 300522431], length 23
```

And I also has disabled both firewall by scripts  like this.

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -t raw -F
iptables -t raw -X
iptables -t security -F
iptables -t security -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

the result sounds good:

```
[root@localhost examples]# ~/disable_firewall.sh
[root@localhost examples]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Oct 14 13:08:28 2017
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [220:24998]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [109:12506]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct 14 13:08:28 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Oct 14 13:08:28 2017
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [692:70796]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [109:12506]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct 14 13:08:28 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Oct 14 13:08:28 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [692:70796]
:INPUT ACCEPT [220:24998]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [109:12506]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [109:12506]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct 14 13:08:28 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Oct 14 13:08:28 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [395:43515]
:INPUT ACCEPT [32:7088]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [17:1020]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [17:1020]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct 14 13:08:28 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Oct 14 13:08:28 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [220:24998]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [109:12506]
COMMIT
```

And both side can ping each other successfully.
So I am confused how the packets are losed unidirectionally only?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for your feedback, I have changed that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your captures, the TCP 3-way handshake is well executed.
The packet sent by the server after the 3-way handshake contains the version string announcement, in your case:

> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1

This packet never reaches the client. 
This can indicate the presence of an **application firewall that silently dropped the TCP session after classifying it as SSH** (also note that the application firewall can operate unidirectionally)

Comment: Didn't firewall blocked all packet together?

Comment: Application firewalls operate at the application level and need to see the TCP payload (after the 3-way TCP handshake) to make a dropping/blocking decision. Do you have such a firewall between your 2 ssh end points?

Comment: Yes, I think so.